# Pandas boolean dataframe search returns False but should be True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

### The Problem

I'm attempting to search through a pandas dataframe to find a single value. The dataframe columns I'm searching through are of type float64.

### Working Example

Here is a working example of what I'd like, with a dataframe of type int64.

```
myseries = pd.Series([1,4,0,7,5], index=[0,1,2,3,4])
myseries
```

The output is the following:

```
0    1
1    4
2    0
3    7
4    5
dtype: int64
```

Now for the search:

```
myseries == 4
```

Results:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

### Not Working Example

Here is a sample of my data.

```
df['difference']
```

Result

```
0    -2.979296
1    -0.423903
2     0.396515
...
48    0.450493
49   -1.216324
Name: priceDiff1, dtype: float64
```

As you can see, it is of type float64.
Now here's the issue. If I copy the value on row 2, and create a conditional statement like before, it doesn't return the True.

```
df['difference'] == 0.396515
```

Output

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
...
48    False
49    False
Name: priceDiff1, dtype: bool
```

Row 2 should be True.
Any assistance at this issue with this issue would be great.
What I believe is happening, is that my query isn't setting the type to float64 and might be assuming it's a different type. I've tested this by downcasting the column type from float64 to float32, with no luck.

Comment: Is this a "comparison of floats" issue? e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python

Comment: Attempted the math.isclose() function and it didn't work either...
Maybe the data has more trailing points than is being displayed? I'm lost.

Comment: df['difference'][2]

0.396515231

Okay, so I was right. When I show the dataframe, it's only showing less sig points than are actually there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use Numpy's [**`isclose`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

```
np.isclose(s, 0.396515)

array([False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your python series stores, or points to, numeric data represented as *floats*, not decimals.

Here is a trivial example:-

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1/3, 1/7, 2, 1/11, 1/3])

# 0    0.333333
# 1    0.142857
# 2    2.000000
# 3    0.090909
# 4    0.333333
# dtype: float64

s.iloc[0] == 0.333333  # False
s.iloc[0] == 1/3       # True
```

As [@piRSquared explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48818395/9209546), use [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for such comparisons. Or, alternatively, [round your data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) to a fixed number of decimal places.